# How can I add a custom column to Windows File Explorer Details View?

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word

I'd like to create a custom property for an office document. Is there any way I can display it on Windows Details View with Visual Basic?

Any hint about this would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I know you can add right-click menu options to Windows Explorer by creating a *Windows Shell Extension* so I would imagine this would fall under the same category.

Comment: Well, from this information (I just know a little bit of VBA) I found that the Metadata Handler provides read and write access to properties stored in a file. MSDN says this can be used to extend the Details view...

Comment: So thanks; but still someone told me (he didn't sound very convincing though) that it was not possible to add a custom column to Windows File Explorer Details View. I'll keep researching though cause it is hard to believe it is not possible, there must be a way to do that (!?).But if you or some knowledgeable person at least knows if yes or no for sure I won't feel like I might be playing stupid researching/studying about it... :)

Comment: Oh, I found that there exists a Shell Extension Handler Column Handlers which which "you can make custom columns available for display" (MSDN). Thought I got it but... "[This feature is supported only under Windows XP or earlier. ]". So it seems it is not possible to do it anymore (!?) wow... So close and then...

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648275/display-custom-header-or-column-in-windows-explorer  It covers much of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Steve that was very interesting. Still, apart from that several have pointed the PropertiesHandler doesn't work properly (or the documentation is a mess), it seems it only works for your own custom files. You can't use it to add properties to office documents for example...

Comment: @Martec Did you find a way to add custom property/column on file explorer for your custom property?

Comment: @sami1592 I got tired of searching. But I might explore it again soon in case things have changed anything. I'd post about it if I get sth positive out of it. Please let me know too if you find something...

Comment: @Martec currently I am looking into it, reading those articles provided above. I have read almost all of it and sadly understood very little, have to go over them again. Next I intend to run that example code provided at the end of that article. My target is to add a custom column to a windows folder.