# Windows explorer - custom sorting column

Tags: windows, sorting, registry, explorer

I am trying to create a custom sorting column in windows explorer. I expect it works the same as adding a context menu item to the right mouse click which you can edit via windows registry. At least I know it's not impossible because the onedrive application has also added a column in windows explorer, see the image below:

[image: The status column is added]

As you can see the status column is added by the onedrive application. Can someone explain to me how I can achieve this. I use windows 10

Comment: Generic custom columns are not supported on Vista and higher.

Comment: One Drive is adding custom columns using Cloud Provider Property Definitions. They are available on Windows 10 creators Update+. Note that the Status column, in particular, is automatically added when you register the Cloud Provider root, this not the custom column. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648275/display-custom-header-or-column-in-windows-explorer/66017828#66017828

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648275/display-custom-header-or-column-in-windows-explorer) for instructions how to do it with .NET:

You have to implement `PropertyHandler`. See Windows SDK `\Samples\winui\Shell\AppShellIntegration\PropertyHandlers`.

It would help if you included your Windows version.