# can i make windows file explorer show certain text extracted from files as a new detail column?

Tags: windows, winapi, plugins, microsoft-file-explorer

I have folders full of log files, and I'd like to display their final status in a column in the folder they are in. That is, in Details view I want to make a new column that shows a piece of text which is extracted from each file. I don't expect to find such a thing out there, and the searches I've tried haven't even yielded a hint about how I would go about writing a plugin to do any such thing. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. Everything is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display custom header or column in Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648275/display-custom-header-or-column-in-windows-explorer)

Comment: Hi Alex K. I don't think that is for me. My files are just text, with a .log extension. Making a special type would only be confusing for other users.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing used to be possible with custom [column handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/column-handlers) shell extensions but Microsoft removed support for those in Vista (3rd-party Explorer replacements might still support them).

Microsofts inadequate replacement are [property handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers). You cannot do this for `.log` files, you would have to invent a `.myapp-log` file extension.

Some people abuse the Windows 10 cloud API to create columns but that only works in specific folders.

If you are looking for a specific string in the last line, you could perhaps use a custom [icon handler](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/797/the-complete-idiots-guide-to-writing-shell-exten-9) for .log files.

Comment: Thanks Anders. I was hoping for a different answer, of course, but it is good to know how things stand. I am indeed looking for a specific string in the last line, but I would like to sort on my custom 'status' column, and I don't think I can sort by icon, only by name.

Comment: Note that some third-party file managers still support the old column handler system, even though Explorer doesn't.